# The base-most Android view that supports gravity

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a custom android widget that abstracts a forum field, **`RecordDataField`**, that is based on a **`RelativeLayout`** (basically groups a field and it's label together, and takes custom attributes to determine where the label is relative to the field, to show a drop down button for dropdown list's, ...)

```
public abstract class RecordDataField : RelativeLayout
{
    protected TextView _tvLabel;  
    protected FieldLayout _rlInput;
    //protected EditText _etInput;
    protected FieldInput _etInput;
    protected Button _btnDrop;

    protected abstract FieldInput InstantiateInput();
}
```

**`FieldInput`** is a subclassed **`EditText`**, nothing really special.

Any child of **`RecordDataField`** implements **InstantiateInput** similar to as follows (**`_etInput`** ultimately ends up with the value returned by **`InstantiateInput`**)

```
protected override FieldInput InstantiateInput()
{
        View v = _inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.RecordDataFields, null);

        _fieldInput = ((ViewGroup)v).FindViewById<FieldInput> Resource.Id.RecordDataFieldInput);

        return (FieldInput)_fieldInput;
}
```

This works great for all my **`RecordDataField`** variants, but they are all **`FieldInput`** (**`EditText`**) based. I now need to go even more general, and when I try changing the abstract method **`InstantiateInput`**'s return type to **`View`**, I run into problems in the base class, b/c it set's gravity and other attributes on **`_etInput`**, and apparently **`View`** doesn't support gravity

```
public virtual void InitView()
{
    _tvLabel = (TextView)_inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.RecordDataFieldLabel, this, false);
    _tvLabel.Text = _label;
    _tvLabel.Gravity = _labelGravity;

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams tvLabelLayout = (ViewGroup.LayoutParams)_tvLabel.LayoutParameters;

    tvLabelLayout.Width = _labelWidth;

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpLabel = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(tvLabelLayout);

    lpLabel.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentTop);
    lpLabel.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentLeft);

    AddView(_tvLabel, lpLabel);
    ...
}
```

Any suggestions as to which view type I can return from **`InstantiateInput`** so this widget can support the greatest amount of view types (the motivation here is that I want to use a **`CheckBox`** in place of the **`EditText`** (**`FieldInput`**)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `TextView (android.widget.TextView)` . Both `Checkbox` and `EditText` extends `TextView` which supports the `gravity` param to support aligning it's content

Comment: I remember there being a reason why I chose EditText over TextView specifically, but cant quite recall. I'll give it a go though, thanks.